# paytabs integration Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, payment

when i add libpaytabs.a file it gives me an error 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayTabCardReaderViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in notificationDetailVC.o
do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Bingo->Try to run in device.
This sdk will not run in simulator. it will give such errors. but in device it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps:

1. you have to make sure your project folder contains one Reachability.h and one Reachability.m files ,
2. and that third library has both these files in it hence the duplicate symbol error when adding the Reachability library.so that reachability.m file that you have added in project, remove it.
3. after removing the duplicate files do a clean build.